# php $_GET doesn't work correctly with ISO-8859-1 characters

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, get, iso-8859-1

I got a database that contains accented letters (like "é" etc) in several fields. If I echo those on my pages they are displayed correctly, because I use this html-tag when I render my html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
```

But when I want to display a value from a parameter from my URL with $_GET it doesn't work.

I use this code:

```
$fname = $_GET['fname'];
```

Actual output:

```
grotÃ©
```

Desired output:

```
Groté
```

The encoding looks OK to me, I checked it using this code:

```
var_dump($fname);
var_dump(iconv_get_encoding('all'));
```

Output:

```
string(6) "grotÃ©" 
array(3) { ["input_encoding"]=> string(10) "ISO-8859-1" ["output_encoding"]=> string(10) "ISO-8859-1" ["internal_encoding"]=> string(10) "ISO-8859-1" }
```

I don't use code where I set the encoding in php. I only use the meta tag, like noted above.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. Websites just can't deal with special characters with ISO-8859-1 encoding. Use UTF-8 encoding instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after further investigation I found a solution!

```
$fnameraw = $_GET['fname'];
$fname = utf8_decode($fnameraw);
```

Now I got the correct output: groté !
While using charset=ISO-8859-1 in my meta tag. Both the database-output as the output from the URL display correctly.